# Fractions swapped

Tags: fractions

I am following an [electronics tutorial](https://youtu.be/gzb5Bw3Wusc?t=3972) (slide 23 [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B69QMG6D5UbIT2t1bXFZQ1Z2OWc/view)) and at some point, he shows the formula:

$\frac{Vs}{Ri} + \frac{Vo}{Rf} = 0$

`Vs`, `Ri`, `Vo` and `Rf` are just variables for voltage and resistance. After some rearanging, it becomes:

$\frac{Vo}{Vs} = - \frac{Rf}{Ri}$

How did the fractions "swap"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{Vs}{Ri} + \frac{Vo}{Rf} = 0$$
$$ \frac{Vo}{Rf} = -\frac{Vs}{Ri} $$
$$ \frac{Vo \times Ri}{Rf} = -Vs $$
$$ Vo\times Ri = -Vs\times Rf $$
$$ \frac{Vo\times Ri}{Vs} = -Rf $$
$$ \frac{Vo}{Vs} = -\frac{Rf}{Ri} $$

Comment: Thank you! I see my mistake now, At step 3 I was multiplying Ri to the denominator too.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{V_s}{R_i}+\frac{V_o}{R_f}=0
\Leftrightarrow \frac{V_o}{R_f} =-\frac{V_s}{R_i} $$

Now multiplying each side by $\frac{R_f}{V_s}$ yields
$$\frac{V_o}{V_s}=-\frac{R_f}{R_i}$$